# Setting vim's background highlight color

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vim, macvim

I am trying to set up vim to behave consistently between my Yosemite installation and another Ubuntu 14 system that I have. The main problem I'm having is with background color highlighting. The desired look is below, from gnome-terminal on Ubuntu:

[image: proper vim color highlighting]

However, when I try to set up the same theme in OSX using iTerm (or terminal.app) I lose the highlighting as vim seems to match the color background to the highlighting background:

[image: incorrect vim highlighting]

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong or some commands I can use to probe how to modify the background color in Macvim so that there is consistency between both interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `set t_Co=8` just before the line `colorscheme solarized`

Typically in Vim, people will have to set `t_Co=256` to get rid of the background highlighting you're referring to. However, it seems that MacVim automatically assumes 256 colors, a result of the GUI.

Through `set t_Co=8`, you'll be overriding that default setting.

In theory anyways?

Comment: You have basically saved my life, worked perfectly. Thank you!